# Event 4740 not being logged on a domain server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have domain environment with server 2008 r2. I am trying to troubleshoot an account that periodically gets locked out but event 4740 is not being logged.

I have checked the status of logging as per a [technet forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/940ed1d8-75f3-4e04-94dd-6f127c13464d/event-4740-not-logged-for-a-single-account-lockout?forum=winserverDS):

**Auditpol /get /Category:Logon/Logoff**

The results I get are:

> Logon - Success and Failure
>
> Logoff - No Auditing
>
> Account Lockout - Success and failure
>
> IPsec Main Mode - No Auditing
>
> IPsec Quick Mode - No Auditing
>
> IPSec Extended Mode - No Auditing
>
> Special Logon - No Auditing
>
> Other Logon/Logoff Events - No Auditing
>
> Network Policy Server - No Auditing

According to these results I should be seeing event 4740 when an account is locked out but it is not recorded. Only event 4625 shows up in the logs.

This problem is intermittent in our domain and seems to have started working on its own but the cause is still unknown.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. I was able to get out of my mind block when you suggested checking the policy setting again. It was not being applied to domain controllers, so I created a policy to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set [Advanced Audit Configuration\Account Management\Audit User Account Management{Success,Failure}](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ca48d92-1f85-40f2-b88c-4f6c4b616cf5/missing-event-4740-on-windows-server-2008-r2-domain-controllers?forum=winserversecurity)?